# JS script for recurring tasks in ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, datetime, servicenow

Our team is trying to develop a script for recurring tasks in ServiceNow. We have a custom table that houses a start_date, end_date, and an interval (number_of_days).  For example, if a task has a start date of 6/6/2019 and the listed interval is 3 days, then we want the script to spit out a task on 6/9/2019, 6/12/2019, 6/15/2019, etc.

At first we thought we could do something like below where we take the date difference between start and end and if there's a remainder of 0, then spit out the task.  This works great if the date diff is 10 for example and the interval is 2 and is nicely divisible.  However, if the date diff is 15 for example and the interval remains 2, then this obviously won't work.

```
if(trigger=='recurring'){
            var milestone_start = performance_start;
            var milestone_end = performance_end;
            var dur = GlideDateTime.subtract(milestone_start, milestone_end);

            var duration = dur.getNumericValue();
            var durationSeconds = (duration/1000);
            var durationDays = (durationSeconds/(60*60*24));

            if(durationDays % days == 0){
                var runScript=new customTaskUtils();
                var x = runScript.applyTasks(case_sysID,milestoneGR.sys_id);
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts on how we can script something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Script is missing something about Today, how do you know if you want to execute today or tomorrow?

You need is to check if the duration is even or uneven. If it's uneven and %2 returns 1, you know you should execute the task. And if it's even and %2 returns 0, you should execute too.

```
if (trigger == 'recurring') {
    var milestone_start = performance_start;
    var milestone_end = performance_end;
    var dur = GlideDateTime.subtract(milestone_start, milestone_end);

    var duration = dur.getNumericValue();
    var durationSeconds = (duration / 1000);
    var durationDays = (durationSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

    var isEven = (durationDays % days == 0);
    var daysSinceMilestoneStart = whichNumberIsTodayInInterval(milestone_start, milestone_end, new GlideDateTime())

    if (daysSinceMilestoneStart == -1) {
        return;
    }
    if (isEven && daysSinceMilestoneStart % 2 == 0) {
        var runScript = new customTaskUtils();
        var x = runScript.applyTasks(case_sysID, milestoneGR.sys_id);
    } else if (!isEven && !(daysSinceMilestoneStart % 2 == 0)) {
        var runScript = new customTaskUtils();
        var x = runScript.applyTasks(case_sysID, milestoneGR.sys_id);
    } else if (daysSinceMilestoneStart == 0) {
        var runScript = new customTaskUtils();
        var x = runScript.applyTasks(case_sysID, milestoneGR.sys_id);
    } else {
      // nothing
    }

    function whichNumberIsTodayInInterval(milestone_start, milestone_end, today) {
        if (milestone_start.before(today)) && milestone_end.after(today) {
            var dur = GlideDateTime.subtract(milestone_start, today);

            var duration = dur.getNumericValue();
            var durationSeconds = (duration / 1000);
            var daysSinceMilestoneStart = (durationSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
            return daysSinceMilestoneStart;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for this!  This scheduled job will execute everyday at midnight. 
 With your suggestion above, I've tweaked the script to basically take the date difference between milestone_start and today.  If that difference has a modulus of 0 AND today's date does NOT exceed milestone_end, then the job will execute.  Does that logic sound right?

Comment: On second though: I think you want to execute on day 0 either way, doesn't matter if the interval is 5 days or 4 days, right? If interval = 2, would it be correct to execute two times in both cases? If not you could divide durationSeconds by numberOfTimesScriptShouldRun and make Dates out of these NumericValues (Unix Time)

Answer (score 0):

The best bet for something like this is to re-do your custom table and extend the `sysauto_script` table.

That gives you all the fields you need to schedule re-occurring work.

You can then add fields like a table selection, template or field selection, and a script box for additional control over setting fields.

Create a script include to run the logic using the fields on the record, and a business rule on the table to set the `OOB` script field on the table to run the script include for the current record.

Then you have a repeatable process for scheduling new recurring tasks, with a simple interface, and a table that isn't going to cost you anything in the license dept (sysauto extensions are free)